# How do you create an array list of objects from a text file and have each object be an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, bufferedreader

How would you be able to import a .txt file and then place each line into an array list as an object, but have each object be an array.

The .txt file looks like this:

```
1 a 1 2 
1 b 0 1 
2 a 2 3 
2 b 0 3 
3 a 3 1 
3 b 0 3
```

I wanted to be able to make each line an object array like so where  so that i could call upon the object and the specific point in the array:

```
<1,a,1,2> 
<1,b,0,1> 
<2,a,2,3> 
<2,b,0,3> 
<3,a,3,1>
<3,b,0,3>
```

and then have an array list where each line (there can be any amount of line hence why i chose an array list) is one thing in the array list. kinda like `<line1,line2,line3,etc..>` so i can use the array list and then the values in the individual arrays within the array list.

This is the code that I currently have and i don't know where to go from here. I am using a buffered reader

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        String inputString = input.nextLine(); 



        try {

            BufferedReader FSMreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));      
            List<FSMline> line = new ArrayList<>(); 
            List<String> currentState = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> inputChoice = new ArrayList<>(); 
            List<String> outputFunction = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> nextState = new ArrayList<>();



            String lines;
            while ((lines = FSMreader.readLine()) != null) {

                line.add(new FSMline(lines.split(" ")));

            }
```

Any help is appreciated because i'm running out of time on a deadline in a class that i am struggling to understand.

thanks

Comment: @VinayHegde I wanted each line to be an array that contains the contents of each line. And then make an array list that contains each array

Comment: You already have an array, but you pass it to the `FSMline` constructor. Don't do that anymore and fix the type of `line`, then you should be done.

Comment: @Tom No it's not done . After getting an ArrayList then I think he wants to access the objects in that each ArrayList and store that to different list/array

Comment: @Tom i'm sorry, i'm fairly new to CS, i dont understand

Comment: @LiamKr If I'm understanding correctly, essentially you're looking for an ArrayList of ArrayLists, each of which contain the Strings? In that case, unless you want to use a custom object, you can change `List<FSMline> line = new ArrayList<>()` to `List<ArrayList<String>> line = new ArrayList<>()`. If you do want to use a custom object, you will need to assign your inner arrays to that object

Comment: @JoshuaBurt close, i want to make an array list of arrays. Do i still follow the same procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't mention the datatype of `FSMline`, I create a collection(array list of arrays) - `List<String[]>` - to store the content of given text file as follows:

```
BufferedReader fsmReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

List<String[]> contentList = new ArrayList<>();
String lines;
while ((lines = fsmReader.readLine()) != null) {
    contentList.add(lines.split(" "));
}

//print the list     
for (String[] content : contentList) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(content));
}
```

Console output:

> [1, a, 1, 2]
>   [1, b, 0, 1]
>   [2, a, 2, 3]
>   [2, b, 0, 3]
>   [3, a, 3, 1]
>   [3, b, 0, 3]

**UPDATED**

And if you want to get the third element of first array in the array list, please use `get(int index)` and `[int index]` to retrieve element from list and array, respectively:

```
System.out.println(contentList.get(0)[2]);
```

Or, you can transform an array into a list by using `Arrays.asList()`, then you can also use `get(int index)`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(contentList.get(0)).get(2));
```

Comment: ok, this is super helpful. How then would I access the numbers inside the arrays inside the array list. Would it be something like ````ArrayList.get(0,2)```` to access to 1 on th first line?

Comment: @i_like_trucks Hi, I updated the way in my post, please check!